# VlookUp: can I reference the range to a cell value

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I am using Google Docs and unfortunately it does not have a `GetPivotData` function.  As I add more categories and subcategories to my data, the Pivot Table data will be moving (column wise).

So I took the liberty to use formulas and find the Row and Column numbers for all my ranges, so regardless of any new data, my range will expand/contract/shift with the correct data.

Now all I have left is to use a `VLOOKUP` to feed the data for that specific subcategory.  I have a cell that shows the value for my range.... my range is `D7:S100`... but like I said, if I add one more subcategory, then my range will be D7:T100 and my cell will reflect this change.  I want to use this cell reference in my `VLOOKUP` so it can be dynamic in the range.

```
VLOOKUP(search_key, range, index, [is_sorted])

VLOOKUP(A1, cell reference, 2, 0)
```

Can the range ever be a cell reference so my vlookup's range be dynamic?

Comment: Do you know whether Google Spreadsheet supports Named ranges? I haven't used it enough but if so, that would be the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Named Range`.  This is available in Google Spreadsheets from the Data menu.

Create a named range to represent your table of data.

[image]

Give it a name like `myTable` or whatever you want to call it, then you can use *that* `Name` in the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP("BOB",myTable,2)
```

If you need to expand the range, just go back in to the Named Range menu and edit the existing range.

I have not tested it yet but if this is like Excel, then you can even define a named range based on a *formula* (typically using the `Offset`, `COUNTA`, `Index` and some other functions to dynamically determine the size of the range).  This is probably available to Google Spreadsheets but I have only done that in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the range ever be a cell reference so my vlookup's range be
>   dynamic?

There may be better ways of achieving what you need to do, but the short answer is yes - using [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?rd=1).

`B1:  D7:T100`

`=VLOOKUP(A1,INDIRECT(B1),2,0)`